# Sort items on a Listview c#

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

Here is my question, I got a listview in which one of the columns I add the name of the files from a certain directory (including the extension) and it can be a number or a string. Lets say i got the following files

```
11.jpg
1.wav
2.mp3
aas.rar
vzs.zip
1ex.exe
```

What i am trying to do is sort them just like on windows, Numbers 1st and then the other ones..

```
1.wav
2.mp3
11.jpg
1ex.exe
aas.rar
vzs.zip
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

check

[Numeric String Sort in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx)